# The first case of the strong Littlewood conjecture

Tags: co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, fourier-analysis, exponential-sums

Let $A$ be a set of $n$ integers and consider the quantity:
$$\int_{0}^1 \left| \sum_{a \in A} e^{2\pi i a x} \right|dx. $$
The (now solved) Littlewood conjecture is the claim that this quantity is lower bounded by $c \log n$ for some universal constant $c>0$.

The (still open) strong Littlewood conjecture is the claim that
$$\min_{A; |A|=n} \int_{0}^1 \left| \sum_{a \in A} e^{2\pi i a x} \right|dx =  \int_{0}^1 \left| \sum_{a=1}^{n} e^{2\pi i a x} \right|dx$$
Or in, other words, the exponential sum above is minimized when the set $A$ is an arithmetic progression. This seems to be a hard open problem not near resolution.

My question is:

> Can one prove the "first case" of the strong Littlewood conjecture. Or, in other words, prove that a three-term arithmetic progression has the smallest $L^1$ norm of any three-term idempotent trigonometric polynomial?

Comment: Have there been approaches to this conjecture based on some notion of entropy?

Comment: Perhaps one could also consider the group of permutations of gaps between the consecutive elements of $A$ leaving the sequence thereof listed in increasing order invariant. In the case of an arithmetic progression, this group should be $\frak{S}_{n-1}$.

Comment: Nice question! I'm actually quite annoyed at myself for not having thought about it before. Just some quick thoughts. It seems like the lower bound $3/2$ holds whenever you don't have a 3-ap. Also, Mcghee-Pigno-Smith (and maybe others) start off with a duality argument, so maybe we can just successfully construct some function to test against.

Comment: @mathworker21 whats the definition of idempotent polynomial here?

Comment: @kodlu I don't know if you meant to ask me, but it means coefficients are idemptotents, i.e. coefficients are such that $x^2=x$, which in the case of $\mathbb{Z}$, means $x \in \{0,1\}$. The point of the more general language of "idemptotent" is that settings other than $\mathbb{Z}$ have been considered in research.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: As mathworker points out, it is just a fancy way of saying 0 or 1 coefficients

Comment: What was the context in which Littlewood conjectured this?

Comment: (I ask because there are several more famous conjectures that have Littlewood's name on it, so it's a bit hard to look up the literature without more keywords)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following human-verifiable proof is in collaboration* with Fedja.

**Lemma** $1$: We have the following for $0 \le x \le 3$: $$\frac{6204}{6750}x^2-\frac{8429}{60750}x^4+\frac{4475}{546750}x^6\le x.$$

> Proof: The above is equivalent to $$\frac{6204}{750}\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^2-\frac{8429}{750}\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^4+\frac{4475}{750}\left(\frac{x}3\right)^6\le x,$$ so letting $x=3y$, multiplying through by $750$, and dividing by $y$, we wish to show $$2250-6204y+8429y^3-4475y^5 \ge 0$$ for $0 \le y \le 1$. The above polynomial is divisible by $1-y$, and dividing yields $$4475y^4+4475y^3-3954y^2-3954y+2250.$$ But $$25\cdot (4475y^4+4475y^3-3954y^2-3954y+2250)$$ $$= 179(5y-3)^4 + (15215y+4638)(5y-3)^2 + 15y+9.$$ $\hspace{130mm}$ $\square$

**Lemma** $2$: For any $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ with $b > a$ and $b \not = 2a$, we have $$\int_0^1 \left|1+e^{2\pi i a \theta}+e^{2\pi i b \theta}\right|^4 d\theta \le 15.$$

> Proof: A quick proof is that when $b=2a$, the integral is $19$ and there are only $4$ nontrivial 4-tuples $(c_1,c_2,d_1,d_2) \in \{0,a,b\}$ with $c_1+c_2 = d_1+d_2$, namely when one is $0$, one is $b$, and the other two are $a$. $\square$

**Lemma** $3$: For any $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ with $b > a$, we have $$\int_0^1 \left|1+e^{2\pi i a\theta}+e^{2\pi i b\theta}\right|^6d\theta \ge 93.$$

> Proof: We wish to lower-bound the number of 6-tuples $(c_1,c_2,c_3,d_1,d_2,d_3) \in \{0,a,b\}$ with $c_1+c_2+c_3 = d_1+d_2+d_3$. Having $|\{c_1,c_2,c_3\}| = 3$ gives $6\cdot 6 = 36$ 6-tuples, having $|\{c_1,c_2,c_3\}| = 2$ gives $6\cdot 3\cdot 3 = 54$ 6-tuples, and having $|\{c_1,c_2,c_3\}| = 1$ gives $3$ 6-tuples. $\square$

**Proposition** $4$: For any $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ with $b > a$, we have $$\int_0^1 \left|1+e^{2\pi i a\theta}+e^{2\pi i b\theta}\right|d\theta \ge \int_0^1 \left|1+e^{2\pi i a\theta}+e^{2\pi i (2a)\theta}\right|d\theta.$$ Consequently, the first (nontrivial) case of the strong Littlewood conjecture is true.

> Proof: Suppose $b \not = 2a$. By Lemmas $1$, $2$, and $3$, we have \begin{align*} \int_0^1 \left|1+e^{2\pi i a\theta}+e^{2\pi i b\theta}\right|d\theta & \ge \frac{6204}{6750}\cdot 3 - \frac{8429}{60750}\cdot 15 + \frac{4475}{546750}\cdot 93 \\ &= \frac{130972}{91125} \\ &> 1.437 \\ &> \int_0^1 \left|1+e^{2\pi i a\theta}+e^{2\pi i (2a)\theta}\right|d\theta,\end{align*} where we used \begin{align*} \int_0^1 |1+e^{2\pi i a\theta}+e^{2\pi i (2a)\theta}|d\theta &= \int_0^1 |1+e^{2\pi i \theta}+e^{2\pi i 2\theta}| d\theta \\ &= \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{\pi}+\frac{1}{3} \\ &< \frac{2\cdot 1.733}{3.141}+\frac{1}{3} \\ &< 1.437.\end{align*}

---

*If this were a paper, Fedja would be an author $99$ times and I once (if lucky).

Comment: Essentially this shows that the problem can be solved with a finite amount of computation. I was previously aware of this (also inspired by Terry's comment to that prior question). It seems to carry this out, however, is not so easy.

Comment: @MarkLewko Answer updated.

Comment: This is very nice! I tried a similar approach with a degree 6 approximation to |x| and convinced myself one needed more terms. Can you explain how you found the polynomial? Have you tried four terms?

Comment: @MarkLewko You want $a_2,a_4,a_6 \ge 0$ such that $a_2x^2-a_4x^4+a_6x^6 \le x$ for all $x \in [0,3]$ and such that $3a_2-15a_4+93a_6 > 1.436 (\approx \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{\pi}+\frac{1}{3})$. Maybe a computer can find such $a_i$'s already, but I at least know how to find them if we just require the first inequality for several (say 10) values of $x \in [0,3]$, and then you can check that the $a_i$'s you get from that in fact satisfy the first inequality for all $x \in [0,3]$ (maybe you need to perturb slightly). There are several polynomials that work.

Comment: @MarkLewko The same polynomial does terrible for $n=4$, and I haven't tried much to find another. I wonder whether a similar proof is possible for $n \ge 4$. For example, for the $n=3$ case, we're kind of lucky since the "next best thing" to an arithmetic progression has the same $||\cdot||_4^4$ norm as a "random" set of integers, namely $15$. When going to $n \ge 4$, the above proof will use really inconsistent estimates for the $||\cdot||_4^4,||\cdot||_6^6$, etc. norms, since, depending on the sign, we use the norm for the next best thing to an AP or for a random set.

Comment: in some sense, the method has to work. One can approximate |x| arbitrarily well on any interval with a long enough polynomial and then compute all possible tuples of even moments up to the degree of the polynomial using the fact that there are only a fixed number of Frieman classes. This is another way of seeing the problem can be resolved for any length with a finite amount of computation.